# Проверка на латинские символы. Текстовые файлы с++

Tags: c++, файлы, проверка

как мне сделать так, чтобы во 2 файл переписалось все, кроме латинских букв, как реализовать саму проверку на латинские буквы. Заранее спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    ifstream t1("file1.txt");
    ofstream t2("file2.txt");
    if (!t1) 
    { 
        cout << "Error of opening of a input-file ";       
        return 0; 
    }
    if (t1 && t2 ) 
    {
        char t;
        if (!t2)
        {
            cout << "Error of opening of a input-file ";
            return 0;
        }

        while (!t1.eof()) {
            t = t1.get();
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Замените ваше `while (!t1.eof()) { t = t1.get();` на `while(t1.get(t)) {`, а то глаз режет...

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал так - убедившись, что `isalpha()` дает `true` только для латинских букв:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream t1("file1.txt");
    ofstream t2("file2.txt");
    if (!t1 || !t2)
    { 
        cout << "Error of opening of a file ";
        return 0; 
    }
    char t;
    while (t1.get(t))
        if (!isalpha(t))
            t2.put(t);
}
```

В крайнем случае, написать такую функцию и самому очень просто:

```
bool isalpha(char t)
{
    return ('a' <= t && t <= 'z') || ('A' <= t && t <= 'Z');
}
```